# Discord api fetch request authorization error

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios

When i run this it always return 401 not authorized i have tried the channel id and token witch are redaced and it works it also works in python yet here it just refuses to.
Please help guys

```js
fetch(`https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/redacted/messages`, {
  mode: "no-cors",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Authorization' : `Bot redacted`,
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    content: message,
  })
})
```

I have tried changing it and using axios but that runs into a dificult to solve cors issue.
Note: this is the oputput(sometimes):
net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)

EDIT: seems like the no-cors option limits the headers and "deletes"
the one i set so you have to call the back end who can than make the call

Comment: Does your bot have the correct permissions? Is your token valid? If your runtime is nodejs, try using the `node-fetch` package.